# jquery.each not works after partial postback

Tags: jquery

```
 var matchedRowIndex;=-1;
       $(function ()
            {
               $(".csstablelisttdsch td:nth-child(1)").each(function (e)
                {
                            //Some code to match row.
                            matchedRowIndex = $(this).closest('tr').index();
                });
            });
```

jquery.each not works after partial postback.

```
$(document).on('each', '.csstablelisttdsch td:nth-child(1)', function (e)
            {
                alert()
            });
```

i ahve used document.on but not works

Comment: It should work, assuming that `.each` portion is ran AFTER the content has been appended.

Comment: There's no "on each" event

Comment: is $(document).on inside a $(function(){})?

Comment: i have call each function after content loaded..It works fine for first time but when i call second time then matchedRowIndex getting -1